# A slang word for people who live in "fantasy land"

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, pejorative-language

Lately I've been searching for a current slang term, used in the US, describing people who live in a fantasy land, or prefer to live in a bubble.

After googling quite a lot, I realized that it's quite hard to search for this kind of thing, as slang is constantly changing and what may have been an excellent fit a year ago is long outdated today.

Any suggestions?

For clarification — The context should be somewhat cynical. The assumption is that living in fantasy is, of course, not recommended.
You can think of it as a cynical slogan saying:  "Not recommended for people who want to live in fantasy land".

Comment: [Very closely related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 10):

Consider *[space cadet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/space_cadet)*:

> 1. (slang, derogatory) One who deals with reality in a way consistent with being under the influence of (or "spaced out on") drugs.
> 2. (slang, derogatory) One who forgets, daydreams, or otherwise is distracted from reality more often than most.

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=space%20cadet&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cspace%20cadet%3B%2Cc0) for *space cadet* shows its use increasing steadily between 1970 and 2004, since which use has flattened out.

Comment: ***spacy*** seems to be related; maybe also ***airhead***.

Comment: Since I can't think of a noun denoting a person who is in la-la land (the other term that instantly came to mind), I'm backing space cadet. Plenty of other terms apply, but they either aren't the right kind of noun or are awfully ephemeral. Oddly, the earliest reference to Space Cadet I can recall is as the title of a Robert Heinlein sci-fi novel for young adults, referring in all earnestness to a student in training for a career in space--written long before astronauts and cosmonauts before them made it out of the atmosphere.

Answer (score 6):

[*La la land*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/la-la+land): Not *very* current but very apt:

> A place renowned for its frivolous activity; a state of mind characterized by unrealistic expectations or a lack of seriousness.

It first was used, I think, for the fantasy life in Los Angeles (where Hollywood is) but generalized to an attitude.

> I'm not sure, but I think I saw her flip me off in my rearview mirror — ah, the ties between the famous and the obscure that bind the fabric of our lives *in La-la land.*

Answer (score 5):

I rather like [*(living) on a different planet*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+on+another+planet).

(At least, that's what my wife says.)

Answer (score 4):

[***have one's head in the clouds***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cloud) is a current expression, and [***live in cloud-cuckoo land (or cloudland)***](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cloud) a less common, yet very [**up to date**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_cuckoo_land) one at the time with D-Day Anniversary.

> have one's head in the clouds: to not know what is happening around you because you are paying too much attention to your own ideas
>
> live in [cloud-cuckoo land](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloud-cuckoo-land), or [cloudland](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cloud+cuckoo+land): to believe that things you want will happen, when they are actually impossible

[***starry-eyed***](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/starry-eyed)

> starry-eyed: having hopes and desires that are not realistic or practical

[***out in left field***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_left_field)

> out in left field: out of contact with reality; out of touch

Comment: I never heard *cloud-cuckoo land*. Is it common? Maybe I'm not up on my slang. :-) It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: @medica: 'Cloud-cuckoo land' sounds very old-fashioned to me, like from some WWII movie.

Comment: @Mitch It's D-Say Anniversary, Mitch. Time for WW2 phrase revival! ;-)

Comment: @Elian Fubar? Battle fatigue? "We had to destroy the town to save it"?

Comment: @Mitch Yeah, things like that! :-)

Comment: @medica et al, “Cloud-cuckoo land” is a phrase from translations of Aristophanes' *[The Birds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Birds_%28play%29)*, 414 BC:  “Pisthetaerus and Euelpides ... name the city-in-the-sky Νεφελοκοκκυγία (***Cloudcuckooland***) ...”

Answer (score 4):

If you want a single word to describe this then the word you're after, only slightly hampered by the fact that it's a very obscure word and almost no one will understand it, is *nephelococcygian*.

It derives from Aristophanes' naming cloud-cuckoo land Nephelococcygia.

Comment: Surely I adopt this word. Nice to learn that *coccyx* is firstly *cuckoo*.

Comment: 'only slightly hampered by the fact that it's a very obscure word and almost no one will understand it' is worryingly descriptive of many other suggestions on ELU.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the person is a [wishful thinker](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wishful-thinker).

And something somewhat negative to say about them is that they are "[off in never never land](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/never-never+land)".

> - an unreal, imaginary, or ideal state, condition, place, etc.

And not creative but probably the most used is "*you are living in your own world*."

Answer (score 2):

There was a 1960s word for such people: *flower children.*

Comment: It may or may not be a reasonable description of what many of them were like, but it's not what 'flower children' actually meant

Answer (score 2):

*dreamer*

> noun
>
> 1. a person who dreams.
> 2. a person who lives in a world of fantasy; one who is impractical and unrealistic.
> 3. a person whose ideas or projects are considered audacious or highly speculative; visionary.

*idealist*

> a visionary or impractical person.

*fantasizer*

> to conceive fanciful or extravagant notions, ideas, suppositions, or the 
>     like (often followed by about  ): to fantasize about the ideal job.

Comment: “Day-dreamer” — proposed by @Suhrud — is even better.

Comment: 3 different answers in one answer, I am supporting Dreamer.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider ***[make-believe](http://esl-dictionary.com/definition/make%E2%80%93believe)*** also. As in, *living in a world of make-believe*.

> things that are imagined or pretended to be true or real
>
> *He has been living in a world of make-believe. [=he has been believing things that are not true; he has been living in a fantasy world]*

It has a current usage also. (See: [Google Ngram result](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20world%20of%20make%20believe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,a%20world%20of%20make%20believe;,c0))

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *daydreamer* is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, I like “day-dreamer”.

Answer (score 1):

You could describe such a person as "a Walter Mitty character" or [Mittyesque](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mittyesque).

The phrase comes from the James Thurber story [The Secret Life of Walter Mitty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Life_of_Walter_Mitty) which was written in 1939 and made into a movie in 1947, but it is current insofar as the movie was [remade in 2013.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Secret_Life_of_Walter_Mitty_%282013_film%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the person is *[spaced out](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spaced+out?s=t)*.

> adjective Slang.
>
> 2) dreamily or eerily out of touch with reality or seemingly so;
>   spacey.

Another alternative:

That person is in his *own world / [dream world](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dream+world?)*

Answer (score 0):

Almost a full day before I see this thread.
I can't believe nobody mentioned *Seeing the world through rose-colored glasses*.

The idiom is a bit more tied to being *overly optimistic* than really *living on another planet than the rest of us*, but depending on context it could be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, the [lotus eaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus-eaters) - [drink the Kool-Aid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drinking_the_Kool-Aid).

> refers to a person or group holding an unquestioned belief, argument, or philosophy without critical examination.

Answer (score 0):

What about 'Away with the fairies'? Probably Irish in origin but a good term for someone who seems to have only a sporadic relationship with reality.